# Source code change notification in Visual SourceSafe possible?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Can we configure Visual SourceSafe server to send email notifications on source code changes to a predefined mailing list?

Best regards
Manav Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly via VSS itself basedd on actual notifications (i.e., without someone polling behind the scenes) TTBOMK, but if you found a tool that could monitor a VSS Shadow directory [that'd you'd need to configure], which would work, even if not pretty...

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two more approaches:

1. By leveraging [VSS Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb509341), but definitely not for the faint of heart,
2. By using a commercial add-on, such as [FileWatch by SourceVizor](http://www.sourcevizor.com/default.php).